# Problemas al consultar Datos con jQuery.DataTables()

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatables

estoy trabajando con jquery.DataTables() en una aplicacion Mvc con Asp.Net

He implementado la consulta de datos a traves de ajax, pero tengo un error y no logro encontrar donde esta, ya que segun la documentacion estaria mal escrito elniombre del action result que me trae la data.

en el Html tengo lo siguiente:

```html
<div id="GridInfoProcesos" class="display">
    <table id="TablaProcesos" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Cliente</th>
                <th>Proceso</th>
                <th>Fecha</th>
                <th>Registros Cargados</th>
                <th>Registros Validados</th>
                <th>Registros Erroneos</th>
                <th>Estado</th>
                <th>Acciones</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Cliente</th>
                <th>Proceso</th>
                <th>Fecha</th>
                <th>Registros Cargados</th>
                <th>Registros Validados</th>
                <th>Registros Erroneos</th>
                <th>Estado</th>
                <th>Acciones</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
```

La llamada Ajax esta definida de la siguiente forma:

```
    <script src="~/Scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //Invocamos el plug-in DataTable , indicamos que el procesamiento lo realizara a través del servidor,
        //indicamos el método y las columnas que se van a mostrar en nuestra tabla
        $('#TablaProcesos').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": "Proceso/GetProcesosKamCliente",
            "columns": [
                { "data": "Id" },
                { "data": "Cliente" },
                { "data": "Proceso" },
                { "data": "Fecha" },
                { "data": "Cargados" },
                { "data": "Validados" },
                { "data": "Erroneos" },
                { "data": "Estado" },
                { "data": "Acciones" }
            ]
        });
    });



</script>
```

y finalmente en el controller tengo el siguiente Action Result:

```
        public ActionResult GetProcesosKamCliente(DataTableRequest model)
    {
        DataTableAdapter<VM_ProcesosCliente> result = new DataTableAdapter<VM_ProcesosCliente>();

        string sKamId = "1";
        string sClienteId = "1";
        int KamId = Convert.ToInt32(sKamId);
        int ClienteId = Convert.ToInt32(sClienteId);

        // obtiene los datos dessde la BD
        TW.Business.Kam.Proceso ck = new Proceso();
        List<VM_ProcesosCliente> lstProcesosKamCliente = ck.GetProcesosKamCliente(KamId, ClienteId);


        //Obtenemos el total de registros de la tabla.
        var totalRows = lstProcesosKamCliente.Count();

        Func<VM_ProcesosCliente, Object> orderByFunc = null;
        //El ordenamiento que vamos a utilizar por default va ser por el Id.
        orderByFunc = item => item.Id;

        //Dependiendo de la columna que seleccionemos indicamos si se ordena por el campo Description.
        if (model.order[0]["column"].Equals("1"))
        {
            orderByFunc = item => item.Id;
        }

        //Obtenemos el valor a buscar.
        var searchValue = "" + model.search["value"] + "";

        var queryItem = lstProcesosKamCliente.Where(d => d.Proceso.Contains(searchValue));
        List<VM_ProcesosCliente> items;
        //Indicamos cual va ser la manera en que se van a ordenar los datos.
        if (model.order[0]["dir"].Equals("desc"))
        {
            items = queryItem.OrderByDescending(orderByFunc).Skip(model.start + 1).Take(model.length).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            items = queryItem.OrderBy(orderByFunc).Skip(model.start + 1).Take(model.length).ToList();

        }

        //Llenamos con información nuestro DataTableAdapter
        result.Data = items;
        result.Draw = model.draw;
        result.RecordsTotal = totalRows;
        result.RecordsFiltered = queryItem.Count();
        //Regresamos la respuesta Json
        return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result), "application/json");

    }
```

el error que me aparece en el depurador de Crome, es 404 (not Found)

```
http://localhost:2911/Kam/Proceso/GetProcesosKamCliente?draw=1&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=Id&columns%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B1%5D%5Bdata%5D=Cliente&columns%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B2%5D%5Bdata%5D=Proceso&columns%5B2%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B3%5D%5Bdata%5D=Fecha&columns%5B3%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B4%5D%5Bdata%5D=Cargados&columns%5B4%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B4%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B5%5D%5Bdata%5D=Validados&columns%5B5%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B5%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B6%5D%5Bdata%5D=Erroneos&columns%5B6%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B6%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B7%5D%5Bdata%5D=Estado&columns%5B7%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B7%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B7%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B7%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B7%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B8%5D%5Bdata%5D=Acciones&columns%5B8%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B8%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B8%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B8%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B8%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&order%5B0%5D%5Bcolumn%5D=0&order%5B0%5D%5Bdir%5D=asc&start=0&length=10&search%5Bvalue%5D=&search%5Bregex%5D=false&_=1543849884874
```

Alguien por favor me podria dar una mano con este tema? 
le he dado muchas vueltas, pero no logro dar con una solucion.
Gracias por leer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Tienes un parámetro que no estas enviado en tu post de la tabla, el ajax.](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/custom_data_property.html)

```
ajax:{
       url: "Proceso/GetProcesosKamCliente",
       dataSrc: { model: getModel() }
}
```

Donde getModel() es la función que te retorna el objeto DataTableRequest. Tú sabrás como retornarlo.

Ahora, respecto a tu controller, solo necesitas generar tu consulta. Las capacidades de draw, paginador, etc., se configuran en el [inicializador de la tabla](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/filter_only.html), junto con la configuracion de las columnas, ajax, etc. En poca palabras, solo manda la data de la tabla.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tus comentarios.. pero me confunde un poco eso que indicas del getModel(). segun entendia, en la url yo invoco el AcctionResult desde donde saco los datos. Para que me sirve el getModel() ? Gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: Es un objeto con las mismitas propiedades de DataTableRequest, que es tu parámetro en el actionResult. getModel es decir que puedes tener una función para llamarla directamente desde el dataSrc del ajax.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu info.. sorry por la tardanza en cntestar. finalmente se trataba de un tema de localizadcion del recurso. Al estar trabajando con Areas, habia que añadir esta en el Path del action Result. Gracias por tu ayuda